# How to easily disable vscode's alternating bracket and parenthesis highlighting

Tags: visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting

I just recently updated my vscode installation to version [1.67.0](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/releases/tag/1.67.0), and am seeing what in my opinion is very aggressive syntax highlighting of all brackets and parenthesis regardless of what theme I have chosen. I find it extremely distracting and would like to have the old behavior back. <s>Oddly, I see nothing in the changes associated with this new version that hints at this change</s> <- EDIT: apparently I just can't read , see accepted answer.

The picture below is the GitHub Light theme, which used to look pretty close to GitHub with all black parens and brackets. Now it looks like a clown.

[image: obnoxious highlighting]

Is there a quick way to disable this? I just want it to be black or whatever the theme originally set them as. I know I can override themes on a per-theme basis, but that seems like a lot of work and is not a permanent fix as I'd have to do it over and over again (not to mention the time figuring out how to do it in the first place). I'm tempted to open an issue on the vscode GitHub as I truly think this is a readability issue, but of course that's my opinion, and I totally get *why* someone would want this.

Answer (score 0):

When posting my original question, I completely overlooked the line item in the vscode release notes which clearly states that Bracket pair colorization was enabled by default. The link in the release notes explains how to disable this feature.

https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_67#_bracket-pair-colorization-enabled-by-default

TL;DR, add this to your settings.

```
"editor.bracketPairColorization.enabled": "false",
```

Or search for "Bracket pair" in the settings UI.